# Converting JS 'escape'd string back to correct format in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, json, character-encoding, asmx

Ok I am trying to send HTML markup back to the server (don't ask). I have managed to do it using jQuery.ajax. But in order for it to reach the WebMethod I have to use JS's `escape` function so things like `<DIV>` end up looking like `%3CDIV%20`. Fair Enough.

I'm sure there must be a built in C# library that will resolve these hex character references for me, surely? Can someone tell me what it is?

I really don't want to include some JSON library just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean *URL Encoded string*.

```
String DecodedString = Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For html content:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string);
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string);
```

For urls:

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string);
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string);
```